# Different configuration sets for components in CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake project with two subprojects, a library and an application using it. The application needs several build configurations (custom values in `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES`). However for the library there is no difference between those configurations. Is it possible to modify the configuration set in subproject and still use it's output in the parent or sibling project?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, did you tried something like this in library project:

```
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Your_custom_config")
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
endif()
```